# Is there anyway to report undeleted accounts that are requesting deletion?

Tags: support, user-accounts

For example [this account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5203/chris-eagle) has "please delete me" in user description and has been inactive for a while. Is there a way to remind an admin the owner of the account desires the account to be deleted?

Comment: The user could have changed their mind about deletion, and opted to stop visiting the site instead. Or could have simply forgotten. This is  a better outcome for the site (votes remain, posts are not orphaned), so I would not go out of my way to make things worse.

Comment: Well this certainly isn't a duplicate of how to delete my account

Comment: The other question makes clear the request needs to come from the user who want to have their user account deleted. The answers here are repeating what the answer for the other question is saying, or implying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't help; the request to delete has to come directly from the user.  This is a two-part process, changing the profile to "please delete me" (to prove ownership) and using the "contact us" form to request deletion.  If the user didn't do the latter, the account won't be deleted no matter what the profile says.

(Well, unless it starts spamming or something, but I mean a regular account with worthwhile contributions.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get the post deleted, you could try contacting the person through the forums, comments(not a good method) or if someone had the users e-mail or other contact information and telling them the proper way that to get deleted. Because as was stated you cannot have them deleted yourself.

Also related,  [How Can I delete my Account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

The best way to do this is tell the person that they have to reach out to the Staff through a [Contact Form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and showing them the info needed to be deleted. But as was stated in the comments it may be better for other users if the account stays un-deleted, as that means votes and other contributions may be deleted as well. Meaning that other users may lose rep.

The person may always change their mind about the deletion.