# The new closing window doesn't take into account if the question has an open bounty

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close, bounties, duplicate-questions

I was inspecting [the new dupe-closing window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930) trying to find something interesting beyond the documented features in it... Haven't found anything *interesting* yet, but stumbled into a bug.

Let's create a situation when there is a question which has a dupe-close-vote or a dupe-flag and then gets a bounty.

No problem. I flag [one of my questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/5020/what-is-meta-should-be-rephrased) as a dupe of a random question (don't blame, I COULDN'T RESIST, what if I had discovered a hidden cookie?). "That solved my problem!" button appears.

[image]

Then I start a bounty. Ok, everything is fine. I can still see "That solved my problem". I think: "Now I see it closed and the bounty removed cuz Community has a diamond!!!" but no.

The truth is cruel.

[image]

So, is there a need in this dialog in this case.

Comment: Still hacking through the edges I see ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The red banner is exactly what moderators or anyone with close privileges will see if they vote to close a question with a bounty. The oddity here is that "That solved my problem!" does not immediately imply the question will be closed. This is a distant edge case, so it probably won't matter much if nothing gets changed. Rather than address the situation in the red box, it probably makes more sense to disable the button on the duplicate banner if there's an open bounty on the question.

Comment: Yes, disabling the button would be more appropriate there.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior makes sense to me. It tells you that you could close this if not for the bounty.  So you can do something about the bounty, i.e., award it or ask a mod for refund if the circumstances warrant.

Also, the second part of the dialog is as meaningful as before (when another user tries to dupe-close).

> "Now I see it closed and the bounty removed cuz Community has a diamond!!!"

I wouldn't expect that. Moderators cancel bounty prior to closing, *then* close. It's no surprise that Community isn't sentient enough to do the first step.