# Confirming that my own question is a duplicate by voting to close should have immediate effect

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, user-interface, duplicate-questions

Someone voted to close my question as a duplicate. I agreed, so I cast my close vote (I have enough reputation to vote to close).

[A question is closed immediately when the asker agrees that it's a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes). So I expected this to happen.

But it didn't. This confused me — is this not a question I asked after all? No, it is. Maybe I need to reload the page? Nope, the question still isn't closed. Is the asker confirmation feature broken? Well, there's the “This question may already have an answer here” banner at the top. What if I click “That solved my problem!”? Ah, that does close the question.

It turns out that only clicking “That solved my problem!” instantly closes the question. Casting a close vote has a different effect, it's just an ordinary close vote.

Please make casting a close vote equivalent to clicking “That solved my problem!”.

Comment: Is it really the same? You could agree with the dupe and thus vote but you could still feel it didn't solve your problem. If not enough voters agree with the dupe your question remains open.

Comment: +1 I agree. -- Please make casting a close vote "on my own question" equivalent to clicking “That solved my problem!”.

Comment: @rene If you object to the “That solved my problem!”, that's a different point. What I want is for a close vote as duplicate on my own question to close it. If I didn't feel it solved my problem, I wouldn't vote to close. (And you may have a point — the other question was another unanswered MSE feature request, so it didn't solve my problem — but anyhow the difference between the two ways to seemingly do the same thing is the issue here.)

Comment: Yessss [do itttttt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257382/comment-author-link-not-a-link?noredirect=1#comment839604_257382)

Comment: Interesting to see it mainly affects long time/high rep users who are used to the existing system.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can't see (due to low reps) how the current high-rep users "duplicate" close vote options look like... All I am trying to say that the current option can be reworded "I agree... and I vote to close immediately" or "I agree... and it solved my problem!". I would like  undelete my answer and reword it BUT can't find the right resource.

Comment: @Hack it looks exactly the same as your flag dialog. You suggest changing the wording in the dialog in case there is existing close vote from others? It wasn't clear from your answer, I thought you meant adding extra, third, button in the banner.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No I did not mean to add third button... I was suggesting the rewording... do you have a screenshot of user when the question is marked as  duplicate

Comment: Not at the moment @Hack sorry.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no problem... thanks for the helping hand. I found the resource... updated my answer

Comment: Just ran across this again today, 7 years later.  In my case, I was the one who cast the initial (and only) close vote.

Comment: "That solved my problem!" is **not equivalent to** "this question is a duplicate"; the wording in the UI is wrong, and incorrectly supposes that the question exists to serve its asker, rather than the site.

Answer (score 7):

I ran across this again today (almost 8 years later) on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69399541/1108305) where I made the initial and only close vote.  I was surprised to see that it didn't close immediately.  Additionally, I don't think the close banner showed up immediately, and didn't see it until I reloaded the page a bit later.

The banner shown was the following:

[image: close confirmation banner]

One thing that stood out to me was the text: "A community member has suggested a similar question that may solve your problem."  While it's true that a community member did suggest it, that community member was me!  So here's another small minor bit of potentially confusing UI workflow and messaging.

Answer (score 5):

I think this can be easily solved by changing the way option(s) are given to choose when OP decides to close his ***own*** question. After all, it's the OP who wants to close the question. I can understand keeping the question *open* so that enough voters can agree upon the reason for the close in case of the *other* users who flagged the question as a duplicate. But, here it's the OP who is actually casting a close vote.

But, if the system is designed (see Note at the bottom) to ask for the confirmation/reason for the close, then how about making a little change (as suggested below) in the dialog box when OP (as the system can detect or already knows the owner of the post) decides to close the question.

As per the OP quote:

> "Someone voted to close my question as a duplicate. I agreed, so I cast
>   my close vote (I have enough reputation to vote to close)".

**Based on the facts, i.e.** :

- OP (the owner) wants to close his *own* question.
- OP has *enough* reputations to cast his close vote.
- System recognizes (by detecting) it's the OP and not any other user.

Everything below ***only applies/valid*** for the above given facts.

Now, upon clicking the '**close**' link under the question body, OP is given the options list as shown below: (Image taken from the [Help Center > Privileges > Cast Close And Reopen Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions))

> [image: Cast a Close Vote]

I would like to suggest the following change(s) to the above shown options window:

1. We could add a button [image: 3] anywhere in the bottom (may be next to "Vote To Close" button). Here, OP can cast his vote by selecting "duplicate" radio button from the options list and then clicking the "That solved my problem!" button. This should close the question *immediately*. Whereas, selecting a "duplicate" radio button from the options list and clicking on the "Vote to Close" button will just cast an *ordinary* close vote.
2. Alternatively, we could change the "**duplicate**" radio button title as "**duplicate... and it solved my problem!**". Now, OP can simply select this radio button from the options list and click on the "Vote to Close" button to cast his close vote. This should close the question *immediately*. No need of "That solved my problem!" button.

With the implementation of any of the above given suggestions, it is possible for the OP to close the question *immediately* without needing an additional confirmation shown afterwards in the *banner* at the top. It will surely avoid the confusion that OP witnessed here in this particular case. I'm sure there are few more other possible ways this can be implemented, but this is what I can think of. Please share your thoughts, ideas any suggestions.

**NOTE**:

I am assuming this belongs to the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) category. Also, the close vote will *not* work (status *by design*) if there's an [open bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250979/the-new-closing-window-doesnt-take-into-account-if-the-question-has-an-open-bou) on the question. It would be great if someone from SE team (or moderators) could share more details on this.

Comment: Why yet another prompt? I said I wanted to close my question as a duplicate of that one. Why ask me “are you sure” again?

Comment: Not even sure I understand this answer, frankly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Please see my edit to post.

Comment: Sorry but you are really over-complicating things here, without a good reason. If OP want to close as dupe of a different question than the one suggested by others then he/she can just cast ordinary close vote like we always did. Otherwise if OP agree it's a dupe of the same question, just clicking the "That solved my problem" is simple and to the point. And the third case, of OP who is not familiar with the new feature and casts ordinary close vote for the same question as other voters is exactly what is being proposed here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for this explanation, reflected in my answer.

Comment: Cheers this makes more sense now. :)