# Hot network questions onebox is invisible in chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

I tried to link to the front page of Stack Exchange in chat today—in other words, to the Hot Network Questions list.  [Unfortunately, it ended up looking like this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24045153#24045153):

> [image: onebox hot network questions list]

The white-on-light-blue is quite hard to read!  But it's even harder to read for other users:

> [image: onebox hot network questions list]

As you can see, it's invisible.  White-on-white text!  Please make it visible.

Comment: This got nothing to do with hot questions. Linking to site front page does not onebox that front page contents. And I wouldn't like to be bombed with 100 questions oneboxed at once anyway.

Comment: Oh, please do tag it however's appropriate.  I only tagged it hot-questions because I was trying to link to the hot network questions list and failing.  (Whatever scheme you guys use here is a mystery to me and will probably continue to be forever.)  I'm not sure what being "bombed with 100 questions oneboxed at once" has to do with my question, though.  If you read the question, you'll see that it's about the text being invisible.

Comment: @snailboat oh, fair enough. So use this link: http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot (it won't get oneboxed)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you!  I'll do that.  I voted to close this as a duplicate of Tim Stone's link.

Comment: IMO stackexchange.com shouldn't be oneboxed to begin with as it's not Q&A site, just a portal, but that should come as a separate feature request.

Comment: BTW you can click the "I agree" button on top to close this right away, instead of voting.

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't spotted that link, I suppose because I had no reason to look at the text of my own question.  I can't think of any reason voting to close should do something other than clicking "I agree".  I'll probably make a feature request for that later, but I'm particularly bad at spotting duplicates on Meta.SE, so I'll have to come back and do it when I have more time to pore through irrelevant results.

Comment: Guess what? [It's already asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261430/confirming-that-my-own-question-is-a-duplicate-by-voting-to-close-should-have-im) ;)