# Question removed as spam, but title still remains in HTML, content visible elsewhere

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, spam

Got a laugh over this one

[image]

([link for 10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271330))

(just realized I screwed up my Freehand Circle--you can see the original title in the tab, as is shown by the html below)

The spam isn't scrubbed from various parts of the html, notably the header

```
<title>produce her with endless orgasms - Meta Stack Exchange</title>
<!-- snip other headers -->
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="produce her with endless orgasms" />
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="[Edit: product name removed - OP] this can be a fashionable aphrodisiac native to Malaysia. In recent years, it has been shown to supply sexual enhancement effects in men because of its ability to boost testosterone " />
```

and answer sort tabs

```
<a href="/questions/271330/produce-her-with-endless-orgasms?answertab=active#tab-top" data-nav-xhref="" title="Answers with the latest activity first" data-value="active">
    active</a>
<a href="/questions/271330/produce-her-with-endless-orgasms?answertab=oldest#tab-top" data-nav-xhref="" title="Answers in the order they were provided" data-value="oldest">
    oldest</a>
<a class="youarehere" href="/questions/271330/produce-her-with-endless-orgasms?answertab=votes#tab-top" data-nav-xhref="" title="Answers with the highest score first" data-value="votes">
```

I think *at a minimum* the title needs to be scrubbed. Scrubbing the title slug may also be warranted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hah!  But I've got a better title :)

Comment: True, you found better spam... ;)

Comment: Huh, I can't just vote it closed, I have to push that butan.  Weird.

Comment: Weird on the verge of silly indeed, go upvote [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261430/confirming-that-my-own-question-is-a-duplicate-by-voting-to-close-should-have-im) now! :-)