# Battle of the Dupe Hammers: OP vs. Gold Tag Badge holder, who wins?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, original-poster

Once upon a time, [dupe hammer was given to gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders). Recently, [question authors aka OP received quite a similar hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate) as well.

Now, suppose OP who has a gold tag badge asks a question with the tag he/she has hammer for, gets a duplicate flag/vote and choose "That solved my problem". Who will appear as the binding close voter? Community♦, or the OP with the gold badge indicator?

Comment: Someone (not me, I have a hammer for [tag:support]) should dupe this question to the second link in this question so we can find out. This OP has a hammer in [tag:support] too!

Comment: Not many [choices...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/support)

Comment: @rene hey, you can cast  close vote! :-)

Comment: Clicking "that solved my problem" is _not_ a vote to close. It's a click of a button that triggers some script that makes Community vote.

Comment: @Woodface makes sense, but there's close vote somewhere behind the scenes, as the question does get closed - so there's a chance it's attributed to the OP.

Comment: @Mart http://i.stack.imgur.com/S40Xh.png!!! :D

Comment: @nicael all that is missing to make that truely perfect is 111 gold badges.....

Comment: maybe more interesting question is, can asker use their hammer more than once. And, how does it look to an asker when there are more than one suggested dupe

Comment: @gnat pretty sure there's no limit, since turns out the Hammer belongs to Community account which possess infinite power. As for more than one dupe it's an excellent question worth another test, and probably a separate support question. :-)

Comment: woo hoo, double-dup test has run and... sorta failed: [“Yes, that solved my problem” forces me to acknowledge or reject all targets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252035/165773)

Comment: @gnat that was kind of expected, but yeah, could have been better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case if OP-holder-of-a-gold-badge approves the vote by clicking "That solved my problem!", it would be attributed to Community anyway, because it just triggers closure, and doesn't really close. So there are no need in useless checks if OP has a gold badge at all (this closing script gets your fkey, but this is made not to allow another users to falsify this button; it is not sent to check, for example, for gold badge or rep, etc).

Unless OP votes to close himself; then the question would be closed instantly without Community, only the name of holder would appear. And after the question is closed, the dupe message disappears, so no more variants there :)

Comment: While this makes sense, would like either hard proof or official response.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Somewhat official](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#comment819126_250930)

Comment: @Woodface thanks, almost there, and if no better answer will arrive guess it would do.

Comment: @Sha wait,  a proof? Test it yourself :)

Comment: @nicael need a close vote first...

Comment: @sha have it :D

Comment: Thanks, proof acquired. ;)