# Profile of Community user: should we add "owning duplicates confirmed by OP"?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, profile-page, duplicate-questions, community-user

Now that [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) has one more [*function*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930), should its description be added to the profile in the "I do things like" section?

Something like:

- owns closing actions on duplicates confirmed by OP

When I first [stumbled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288729/community-moderator-closing-duplicates) in the question marked as duplicate by Community user, I looked at her profile but it didn't list this particular role.

Comment: Community's a her?!!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ let me think so :)  anyway, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer#comment802362_245123

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - I originally used a gender-neutral `it` but was overridden.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, we give users a lot of leeway in choosing what to put in their profile.

We did try to ask Community nicely whether this was an appropriate change. However the answer was a long silence. I assume this is not going to happen.