# Is the message "This question may already have an answer here" shown after flags or only after close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

In some situations the banner is displayed which says that: "This question may already have an answer here" (followed by a link to the other question). Simultaneously, two options are shown: "that solved my problem" or "No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how."

This was introduced here: [Can we clarify to the OP that their question is not yet closed and the duplicates are only suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930)

I would like to know whether this means that somebody actually voted to close the question. Or whether this appears also in the case when somebody used exact-duplicate flag. (This is typically done by users who do not have sufficient reputation to cast close votes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog appears once there's *one or more "exact duplicate" flags or votes*.

In the first case (flags), however, flagger does not get any credit in the resulting banner (if the question is finally closed), so there might be some confusion.

Comment: Both posts linked are about the same problem. The post they linked led to the new feature being implemented (and the feature is explicitly mentioned in the answer). However, the banner itself existed *long* before either of those posts were ever created - the confirm button just wasn't there before.

Comment: @ani yep, I did forget that.