# Make share, edit, etc buttons larger to enhance new user experience

Tags: feature-request, design, action-buttons

Please make these links a bit larger:

---

share / edit / delete / flag

---

I'm pretty sure a lot of new users might be having trouble finding these buttons after posting a question, It took me a while finding them too. And for the moment I thought there was no way to edit to post.

Comment: I disagree they should be larger, but a little help finding them is not bad. Have my vote.

Comment: ideally these would be larger for an asker, or better yet for an asker under some rep threshold (125 or 200 or 100 etc). Other users could see things as these are now (inspired by approach of a ["this solved my problem" banner visible only to asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/165773))

Comment: they at least need to be similar size as Tags

Comment: Their font size is actually larger than the tags. The tags just steal more focus because they have a background and border, whereas the buttons are plain text and grey.

Comment: @animuson So am alternative solution is here: Give them backgrounds and borders

Comment: I have no problem with the current buttons, but my suggestion on this issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314756/379894