# New members can't find logout button

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, logout

From time to time we receive questions about logout button on ru SO:

1. [Как выйти с учетной записи в Stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7727/15479)
2. [Как выйти с аккаунта на сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6691/15479).
3. [Где кнопка Выход?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7363/15479)
4. [Подскажите, как выйти из аккаунта на сайте stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5510/15479)

New members can't find it.

Usually this button is located on the bottom side of the menu. GitHub, Facebook, etc...

[image]  [image]

On SE sites location of this button is not, hm, obvious.

If you don't want to move it, you can, at least, make it bold:

```css
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
```

Even with this small change the button will be more evident.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if the second solution will resolve the issue. As for me and my monitor, the difference is barely noticeable, especially since a user does not expect to see it in that corner.

Comment: possilby better move log out to line with `CURRENT COMMUNITY`, [something like this](//i.imgur.com/QWjT8NP.png)

Comment: @Arhad I'm not the UX guru. Just pointed out the problem )

Answer (score 4):

There is a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in the StackExchange Network sites, which introduces users to the basics of each community and how to contribute.

Maybe, there should be a ***user interface tour*** too.

The location of the StackExchange speech bubble is the upper right corner, which is where usually options are located. This can also be seen in the screenshots from GitHub and Facebook.
However, people are used to click on profile pictures to get these options, including logout.
The hover card (tooltip) of the speech bubble states that it is *a list of all 174 StackExchange sites,* which makes it lesser obvious.

But it is common knowledge, that the logout option is usually located somewhere in a menu in the upper right corner, so it could be guessed.

---

## **TL;DR:**

I believe that icons would make a larger visibility difference than bold text.
[image: Sample image of user interface.]