# The 'Share', 'Edit', 'Follow', and 'Flag' buttons are not obvious

Tags: feature-request, design

The 'Share', Edit', 'Follow', and 'Flag' text buttons are very well hidden below a post in a hard-to-distinguish font and colour without any icons.

I've been using Stack Exchange for a few years intermittently, and I have found myself searching the entire screen scrolling up and down for these buttons on various occasions. I'm not a UI expert, but wouldn't it make more sense to place them at the top right of a post with an obvious difference of some sort like an icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the share, edit, close, flag, ... buttons more obviously buttons, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313935/make-the-share-edit-close-flag-buttons-more-obviously-buttons-please) - found in the "Related" section on the right side.

Comment: Yes thanks, that's essentially the same point.

Comment: I actually _really_ like the clean design. Too often too much gets hidden behind icons. On SE, the placement of these actions is consistent, and imho, logical.